# How do I control the "original version" for optimistic concurrency in EF?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, optimistic-locking

EF has built-in support for optimistic concurrency (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx).  In this case, I want to leverage that capability, but I don't want the "before" object to be what I just pulled from the database.  Instead, I want it to be something I pulled a while ago (and stored the rowversion value of).

Is it possible to "fake" the object for that purpose?

The use case is a webpage that shows some data.  When the user saves the form, I want to check that no other users have already saved the data...

Comment: so the concurrency check throws an error. You still have the POCO version as maintained by front-end.   No need to reload.  I dont see the issue.

Comment: I can compare the new version to the old version manually and then throw an error, but I guess I was hoping to hook into the automatic EF mechanism for doing it...

Comment: yes ef Does it for you using Rowversion. It will do optimistic check and throw an error.  The generated SQL will have an extra WHERE Rowversion = Rowversion.  If the record was changed, this update fails.   So im not sure what you mean by manually check.  Its not necessary IF the POCO has rowversion/timestamp defined